# Find the differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

What is the differential equation for 
$ y = Ln(cos(x - c_{1})) + c_{2} \ , \quad c_{1} , c_{2} \in \mathbb{R} $

$ y^{\prime} = -tan(x-c_{1}) $ , and hence $ y^{\prime \prime}= - (1+tan^{2}(x-c_{1})) $.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't understand your use of symbols. What is $t$, $g$?

Comment: tg is symbol for is tangent.

Comment: What kind of equation are you looking for? For example, $y'=-\tan(x-c_1)$ is a perfectly valid one.

Comment: I want find $ c_{1} $ and $ c_{2} $.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Up till what you have done is perfectly fine:

$$y^{\prime} = -\tan(x-c_1) $$

Now, we know that: $\tan (-x) = -\tan x$. Thus, we can write:
$$y^{\prime} = \tan(c_1-x) $$
$$\arctan y^{\prime} = c_1-x $$

Now, differentiating with respect to $x$:
$$\frac{1}{1+(y^{\prime})^2}y^{\prime \prime} = -1$$

Rearranging:
$$y^{\prime \prime} + 1 + (y^{\prime})^2 = 0$$